# preload NSURL via didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and call in ViewController-webview

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, nsurl, preloader

I want to preload an URL via " didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" if my app starts. 
At this time I call the URL in the ViewController directly, but it takes too long to the the content, so I want to see the content from the URL directly.

***At this time in my ViewController viewDidLoad:***

```
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"URL_today",@"URL-Calendar")]]];  // I localize the URL ;-)
loadingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:(nil) repeats:YES];
```

**So, I think I have to create a method in my AppDelegate.**

```
- (void) callURL{
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"URL_today",@"URL-Calendar")]]];
loadingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:(nil) repeats:YES];}
```

Than call the method in the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

```
[self callURL];
```

**And now I have to call the result in my webView in the ViewController - viewDidLoad:**

```
[URL-RESULT-show ]
```

Has anybody an idea, how to do it? THANKS.

Comment: kindly improve your accepted rate

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110460/how-to-improve-accept-rate-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Yes, you made 18 questions and accepted 5.